# Calculating the final sum of an investment with a specific daily growth of rate over a period of time.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, statistics, summation

Calculating the final sum of an investment with a specific daily growth of rate over a period of time.

I do apologize if this question is very basic for the vast majority of people in this forum but after my long research over the internet for an answer has failed I came here hoping I could find a clear explanation for this simple problem.

For the sake of clarification, I am going to use the following hypothetical example:

Let's say, I am promised to make %01 of profit every day on my investment of a $1000

The first day it is going to be: 1000 + (1000 * 0.01) = 1010

The second day it is going to be: 1010+ (1010* 0.01) = 1020.1

The third day it is going to be: 1020.1+ (1020.1* 0.01) = 1030.3

The fourth day it is going to be: 1030.3+ (1030.3* 0.01) = 1040.6

and so on.

[short python method code showing the calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqXU8.png)

so my question, since the actual amount of investment changes on daily bases, what mathematical formula can I use to calculate the final sum after a specific number of days, for example after 100 days?

Noting that using the following formula ( number of days * growth rate * originally invested amount) does not work because that does NOT take into consideration the added profit every day to the originally invested amount.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You wrote $10\%$, but in your computations you use a $1\%$ profit rate.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I just edited the mistake.

Comment: This is called *compound interest*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial amount is $M$ and if your profit rate is $a$ (in your example, $M=1\,000$ and $a=0.01$, then,after $n$ days, the amount of money that you have is $M\times(1+a)^n$. For instance, if $M=1\,000$, $a=0.01$ and $n=4$, you get$$1\,000\times1.01^4=1\,040.604\,01.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! that is exactly what I was looking for. If you do not mind me asking another question, is there a name for this concept or this formula.. ? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know whether or not the *formula* has a name, but what we are talking about here is [exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - Hi Dr. Santos, is there really a difference between *a rate* and *a rate of change*? After a thinking about this and googling for awhile I noticed some authors define a rate in the following way: *a rate is the ratio between two related quantities in different units*. On the other hand, I've seen a rate of change defined in the following way: *a rate of change is a rate that describes how one quantity changes in relation to another quantity*. It seems like both of them can be defined by the first definition, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Is your question related to my answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:  Not directly it seems, however, as I was reading this post - your answer included - it got me thinking and this question popped into my head. Your feedback would be greatly appreciated if you have the time.

Comment: @TaylorRendon A rate of change is a particular type of rate: it is the rate between the way two related quantities change.